# Django-mptt сделать запрос на чистом SQL

Tags: django, django-orm

Доброго все времени суток. В общем проблема в выполнении запроса к БД Вот такой вот код работает нормально

```
ContentCat.objects.all()
```

Но проблема в том что мне этих данных мало. Вопрос в том можно ли каким либо образом заставить Django-mptt работать с вот таким вот кодом?

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT cc.id, cc.name, cc.parent_id,
             (SELECT COUNT(*) 
              FROM content c 
              WHERE c.cat_id = cc.id) AS count_articles 
              FROM content_cat cc""")
```

А конкретнее с

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(""Any SQL""")
```

Потому как я SQL знаю более менее а Django ORM как говорят на хабре глупый как палка

Comment: Покажите модели. Врут все про Django.

Comment: Уже разобрался вот таким методом ContentCat.objects.extra(
                 select={"count_articles":"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM content WHERE content.cat_id = content_cat.id"})

Comment: У Django есть также метод `annotate`, и аггрегатор `Count`. Если у Вас правильно настроены связи, можно было вообще без SQL обойтись. Мешать SQL в Django не есть хорошо.

Comment: Также, если Вы нашли решение проблемы, пожалуйста, оформите его в виде ответа к своему вопросу.